# Node.js Puppeteer - Find text in web Page

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, selector

I try to click on a selector only if I can find "LoginID" text in a web page:

```
if ((await page.content()).includes("LoginID")){
        await page.waitForSelector('#selector1')
        await page.click('#selector1')
}
```

I'm not really sure this is the best way to do it.

Can someone confirm it to me please ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This seems reasonable, but it depends on the page. "Best" is a pretty relative term. Please add more details about the actual use case. Thanks.

Comment: This is a valid usage, if you haven’t experienced any downsides, use it without worry.

Comment: Thank's for all return. This code does not seem to work in my case. In fact I'm not sure that a really find the text and clic on the selector. When I sign in twice, I get an error message and I have to click on this selector to sign in. Looks like the code never goes through this simple loop.